# Orientation Builder gives wrong orientation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my application I'm using a `GridView` to display a grid of categories and a `TextField`. I want to change number of items displayed in one line based on `Screen Orientation` (i.e when in `Portrait mode 5 items per line` and in `landscape mode 8 items per line`).

I'm trying to achieve this by using `OrientationBuilder` widget. It works perty fine until i open softkeyboard to edit the TextField.

But when i open softkeyboard the OrientationBuilder returns orientation as `landscape` thus leading to overflow issues.

Here is my code,

```
return new Scaffold(
      appBar: buildFilterAppBar(context),
      body: new OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
        return new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildContentTitle(
                      context, true, Icons.local_offer, '', 'Choose category'),
                  new GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 5 : 8,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: buildCategories(orientation),
                  ),
                  new Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      buildContentTitle(context, false, null,
                          'assets/money_pouch.png', 'Set a price range'),
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 44.0),
                        child: new Text(
                          'Price (\u20B9)',
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 44.0, right: 12.0),
                        child: new Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Flexible(
                                child: new TextField(
                                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'From'),
                                )),
                            new Container(
                              width: 1.0,
                              height: 40.0,
                              color: Colors.grey[700],
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                            ),
                            new Flexible(
                                child: new TextField(
                                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'To'),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new MaterialButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              minWidth: double.infinity,
              child: new Text(
                'APPLY  FILTERS',
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
```

Is there any other option rather than using `OrientationBuilder` or is there any way to rectify it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `OrientationBuilder` works perfectly fine for me. You might just double check and debug your application or create an issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Comment: I've made sure if that. When I open soft keyboard, the state of the widget changes as expected. But the orientation was landscape.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It's already said in the documentation that

*`OrientationBuilder builds a widget tree that can depend on the parent widget's orientation (distinct from the device orientation).`*

In my case when soft keyboard is opened, width of the screen becomes greater than height(Note that I'm calculating the height as `Full Screen Height - Soft Keyboard height`).

Thus OrientationBuilder returns as `landscape` which is the `correct behaviour` as per documentation.

Hence `OrientationBuilder cannot be used` for this case.

To solve the issue we can use orientation obtained from `MediaQuery`

```
MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 5 : 8
```

Comment: Thanks sir for sharing this

Comment: Several years later after realising this and I still had to come back to find out what was wrong a second time...